# Check Condition Dynamically usin array : Jquery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

This is static condition

```
var as = $(json).filter(function (i, n) {
    return n.website === 'yahoo' || n.website === 'ebay'
});
```

but want to check dynamically suppose my array value is

```
weblist[0] = "yahoo";
weblist[1] = "google";
weblist[2] = "ebay";
weblist[3] = "rediff";
weblist[4] = "amazon";
```

I want to check condition using above array value something like this

```
var as = $(json).filter(function (i, n) {
    return n.website === 'yahoo' || n.website === 'google' || n.website === 'ebay' || n.website === 'rediff' || n.website === 'amazon'
});
```

how can possible ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Array.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) on the `weblist` to filter elements that are in the array `weblist`

```
var as=$(json).filter(function (i,n){
     return weblist.indexOf(n.website) !== -1
});
```

**[Polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Polyfill)**

indexOf was added to the ECMA-262 standard in the 5th edition; as such it may not be present in all browsers. You can work around this by utilizing the [following code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Polyfill) at the beginning of your scripts. This will allow you to use indexOf when there is still no native support. This algorithm matches the one specified in ECMA-262, 5th edition, assuming TypeError and Math.abs have their original values.

**Edit**

You can also try using jQuery funciton [jQuery.inArray()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.inarray/) for better cross browser / version compatibility.

Comment: If you only need to support IE9+ that is

Comment: If you need to support older versions of IE, there's an [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Polyfill) on the MDN site Adil linked.

Answer (score 1):

```
var as = $(json).filter(function (i,n){
    return $.inArray(n.website, weblist) >= 0;
});
```

Comment: I was wondering why someone downvoted this answer, as this is the correct (jQuery) way to do it. +1.